# MATLAB animated splash screen using gif

Tags: matlab

I'm creating a MATLAB executable application. And when creating an executable in MATLAB they give you an option to add a splash screen. I've tried this with normal images, png and jpg. But I wanted to use an animated image, like a loading gif image. Because my program takes a while to compile and execute, I want the user to know that it is loading so they don't quite or not exit. I tried to add a gif image to my splash screen, but it didn't work. It just displayed a still image. Is there any way to add an animated splash screen or gif to my executable MATLAB application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can. But what you can do is to display the GIF in a window and update each frame every x seconds. Here's an example

```
% Read in your GIF file. Don't forget to read in the colour map as it is
% required for display.
[I, map]=imread('http://i.imgur.com/K9CLvNm.gif','Frames','all');

% Create a figure to hold your splashscreen
hfig=figure;
set(hfig,'Menubar', 'none');
set(hfig,'name','Please wait. Loading...','numbertitle','off');

% Set a timer to dynamically update the plot every 0.1 sec
t=timer('TimerFcn', {@timerCallbackFcn, hfig, I, map},'ExecutionMode','FixedRate','Period',0.1);

% Start the timer
start(t);

% Do your stuff here
for j=1:10
    pause(1);
end

% Clean-up
stop(t);
delete(t);
delete(hfig);
```

and then create the timer update function in a file called timerCallbackFcn.m

```
% This is the timer function to update the figure. 
% Save as timerCallbackFcn.m
function timerCallbackFcn(hTimer, eventData, hfig, I, map)
    figure(hfig);

    % i is the frame index
    persistent i;    
    if isempty(i), i=1; end

    % display the i-th frame in the GIF
    imshow(I(:,:,i),map);    

    % increment frame index i
    i=i+1;
    numframes=size(I,4);
    if (i>numframes), i=1; end
end
```